# 65Mbps with 40MHz 2.4 GHz WiFi N

Tags: wireless-networking

Why do I have such slow speed?

I have 4 other WiFi networks with 4+ signal around me. The speed is 72 Mbps after connecting, but after 5 sec. it drops to 65 Mbps. My laptop doesn't the support 5 GHz band.

My settings:

[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Kindly read http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

802.11n spec is very specific on the fact that it is to drop to a 20MHz channel if there is *any* overlap.  As you have 4 other networks around you, the odds are pretty good you're stepping on at least one other network.  As to why it connects and then slows... signal quality and/or "low power" (most systems will slow the radio to save power when idle.)

Comment: +1 - many enterprise wireless systems now default to leaving 40mhz channel bonding disabled on 2.4ghz as it's nearly impossible to achieve this without overlap unless you own the building(s)..

Comment: Thank you! I hate manufacturers stating 130, 300, 10000 Mbps unless you have your own building without walls etc.